# Webstorm Chrome Extension doesn't stay installed

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, angularjs, webstorm

I followed Vojta's video about how to do debug angularjs in Webstorm.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVw8N3hTfCI&feature=plcp

However, every time I stop the testacular server in webstorm.  I have to reinstall the webstorm debug extension for chrome.  Am I doing something wrong?  Do I need to install it into some Chrome profile or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working OK this morning. I think I was running testacular from the command line as well, which was using up the default port of 9876 and was giving me unexpected results because my webstorm testacular server was running on 9877 instead, but I had configured webstorm debug to run on 9876.

All good now.